# Picamera as streaming server

Tags: camera, vlc

I am implementing a video streaming server with picamera (it is a requeriment), but i can't test it...
I am executing this example for the server:

```
import socket
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 24

    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
    server_socket.listen(0)

    # Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
    connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
    try:
        camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
        camera.wait_recording(60)
        camera.stop_recording()
    finally:
        connection.close()
        server_socket.close()
```

from the picamera [web](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.5/recipes1.html#recording-to-a-network-stream)

On the client side, I am testing the server with VLC as it is explained on the web. The command is

```
vlc tcp/h264://ip_to_connect:8000/
```

In order to avoid network problems, I executed VLC on the Raspberry Pi but it doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

```
[0x18c78f0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface. 
[0x1ab0ba0] main input error: Invalid PCR value in ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR ! 
[0x1b68548] xcb_xv vout display error: no available XVideo adaptor
[swscaler @ 0x1b76060] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb565le.   
[0x1abf618] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)  
[0x1abf618] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)   
[0x1abf618] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
```

I tried to change the format (to mjpeg) but it seems to be an incorrect format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the uv4l driver + streaming option, i only required one connection for streaming through a website.

[This tutorial worked for me](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14)

I used : uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --width 640 --height 480 for letting the thing stream though :) . The default encoding worked faster for me then specifying JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this gstreamer recipe http://archpi.dabase.com/#sending-and-receiving-pi-camera-video-over-the-network

Answer (score 0):

VLC (or mplayer) aren't capable of playing back much on the Pi; they're not optimized for videocore GPU, so they're trying to do everything on the CPU (which is nowhere near powerful enough for video decoding). You can try playing back with omxplayer (which is) but I don't recall whether it's capable of playing back a network stream (probably possible with `netcat` or something similar).

I'll add a note to the docs for 1.7 that VLC/mplayer should be run on a "normal" machine, not the Pi.